# Sound is being cut off

Tags: raspbian, audio, hdmi

On the raspberry pi connected to an hdmi TV, any command that emits sound has the first two seconds of audio cut off. Numerous options have been enabled in config.txt. How do you make it play audio without being cut off?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and using `vcgencmd force_audio hdmi 1` fixed it.
I found it here : https://github.com/alexa-pi/AlexaPi/wiki/Devices#raspberry-pi

Also for Pulseaudio I had to comment `load-module module-suspend-on-idle` in `/etc/pulse/default.pa`

Comment: This did not help to me. My Raspberry is connected via HDMI to a screen but without audio. I'm using a external speaker which is also connected to a USB sound card (I'm using a microphone).